# Change the background of button in windows phone programmatically

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In this case how can i change the background programmatically ?

```
        <Button x:Name="ButtonPlayBack1" Tag="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="60" Width="70" Click="ButtonPlayBack_OnClick">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/images/bubble_right_grey.png"/>
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

XAML:

```
        <Button x:Name="ButtonPlayBack1" Tag="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="60" Width="70" Click="ButtonPlayBack1_Click" BorderThickness="0">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/images/bubble_right_grey.png"></ImageBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

CS:

```
private void ButtonPlayBack1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage bit = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png", UriKind.Relative));
    ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
    brush.ImageSource = bit;
    ButtonPlayBack1.Background = brush;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , yes it works ... but i need to use ControlTemplate .

Comment: for that binding would be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution :

```
Grid grid = ButtonPlayBack1.GetLogicalChildrenByType<Grid>(true).First();

if (grid != null)
grid.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(backGroundSrc, UriKind.Relative)) };
```